# How can I type in Malayalam on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: language-support, ibus, malayalam

How can I type Malayalam in Ubuntu 16.04? I tried installing `swanalekha` using `sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n m17n-contrib`. I don't see an option for swanalekha in text entry.

Comment: You need to make sure that _IBus_ is the selected input method in _System Settings -> Language Support_. You also need to relogin before the `ibus-m17n` entries are available in _Text Entry_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install Malayalam language packs. To do that, go to System settings --> Language support --> <kbd>Install / Remove Languages ...</kbd>

Search for Malayalam and check the related box **☑**

[image]

Then click on Apply. (NOTE : You need to have a working Internet connection for downloading related packages.)

After installing the language, go to System Settings-->"Text Entry" and click on <kbd>+</kbd> and search for related input methods.

[image]

And click on <kbd>Add</kbd>.
After adding , press <kbd>Super (Win)</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between installed input methods. You can type in Malayalam when input method is set to Malayalam ( <kbd>Ml</kbd> on right top of your screen )

Comment: The poster above me missed out on a small detail that catches a lot of folks. iBus. Here's the article I just found on making this work. I can't take credit for it, the author who wrote it is great... https://swanalekha.smc.org.in/#linux