# How to download and install swanalekha malayalam language phonetic software for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: malayalam

How to download and install Swanalekha - scim-ml-phonetic for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Brief search on https://packages.ubuntu.com gives the following package names - `fcitx-table-malayalam-phonetic` (*Flexible Input Method Framework - Malayalam phonetic table*), `language-pack-ml` (* translation updates for language Malayalam*), `language-pack-gnome-ml` (*GNOME translation updates for language Malayalam*). Also see ["How to type Malayalam in Ubuntu?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/142977/66509).

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/785167/how-can-i-type-in-malayalam-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

1.Open terminal
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
type enter
type password
After installation restart computer
2.Go to settings-region and languages-click on plus button-type Malayalam-select other-select malayalam(swanalekha)-add
Restart Computer
3.Install appropriate font.